# How to use webpack for pack node program

Tags: node.js, webpack, bundle, node-modules

Can you provide me an example how to use webpack for pack node js project to single file with dependencies?

I wrote webpack config, but its not working, because is packed only first (index.js) file. Whats is wrong with my script?

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function (x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'backend.js'
    },
    externals: nodeModules,
    plugins: [

    ],
    devtool: 'sourcemap'
}

src/index.js
src/library.js
src/library2.js
```

How to pack into single file with dependency from `node_modules`?

Answer (score 1):

You should install webpack.
This is install command:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@2.3.3 --cache /tmp/empty-cache --global
```

`2.3.3` is version of your project.

You can specify version and then use this command:

```
webpack -w
```

It will work.

Comment: It exported only './src/index.js', file too